# Sum of nodes in json file

Tags: json, r, spatial

I have a geojson file `routes` read into R - it is made up of polylines, the nodes of which are nested within a list which is nested within another list.  For example

```
> routes$features$geometry.coordinates[100]
[[1]]
          [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] 73.84602 18.55718
 [2,] 73.84423 18.55659
 [3,] 73.84410 18.55727
 [4,] 73.84305 18.55938
 [5,] 73.84225 18.56014
 [6,] 73.84114 18.56156
 [7,] 73.84080 18.56167
 [8,] 73.83027 18.56258
 [9,] 73.81804 18.56283
```

My objective is to count the number of nodes for every feature and subtract by 2 (the start and end points), and then add all of the nodes together.

```
> str(routes)
List of 3
 $ type    : chr "FeatureCollection"
 $ crs     :List of 2
  ..$ type      : chr "name"
  ..$ properties:List of 1
  .. ..$ name: chr "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
 $ features:'data.frame':   166 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ type                 : chr [1:166] "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" ...
  ..$ properties.properties: logi [1:166] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ properties.features  : logi [1:166] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ geometry.type        : chr [1:166] "LineString" "LineString" "LineString" "LineString" ...
  ..$ geometry.coordinates :List of 166
```

I wrote the following function which prints a list of sum of nodes, but how would one sum them up all in one function?

```
 for( i in routes$features$geometry.coordinates[1:166]){
  print(length(i-2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sapply` loop through the coordinates and return the `nrow` of the matrix (`-2` here according to your logic) and then sum them up:

```
sum(sapply(routes$features$geometry.coordinates, function(mat) nrow(mat) - 2))
```